How to deal with different reference & smart-pointer types
I'm a bit confused about how to handle the different reference and smart pointer types in this example:
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Data{}

trait ApiClient {
    fn load_data() -> Vec<Data>;
}

struct HttpApiClient {}

impl ApiClient for HttpApiClient {
    fn load_data() -> Vec<Data>{
        todo!()
    }
}

struct PageA<'a, A: ApiClient>{
    dep: &'a A
}

struct PageB<A: ApiClient> {
    dep: Rc<A>
}



struct PageC<A: ApiClient> {
    dep: Arc<A>
}


enum Pages<'a, A: ApiClient>  {
    A(PageA<'a, A>),
    B(PageB<A>),
    C(PageC<A>)
}

struct Application<'a, A: ApiClient> {

    current_page: Option<Pages<'a, A>>,
    dependency: Arc<A>

}

impl <'a, A: ApiClient> Application<'a, A> {
    fn new(dependency: Arc<A>) -> Self {
        Application {
            current_page: None,
            dependency
        }
    }

    fn page_a(&mut self) {
        // I cannot construct PageA here because it requires a reference to the ApiClient.
        // When using .as_ref the reference is not valid long enough
        todo!()
    }

    fn page_b(&mut self) {
        // I cannot construct PageB here because it requires a Rc<ApiClient> but I have an Arc<ApiClient>.
        todo!()
    }

    fn page_c(&mut self) {
        self.current_page = Some(Pages::C(PageC { dep:self.dependency.clone() }));
    }

}

fn main() {
    todo!()
}

This simplified example illustrates my issue. I have an Application struct that can display one of three different pages. Each page has a dependency on an instance of the ApiClient trait, and here's where the problem arises:

PageA requires a regular reference (&ApiClient).
PageB requires an Rc<ApiClient>.
PageC requires an Arc<ApiClient>.

The Application struct initializes these pages on demand, but since it holds the dependency as an Arc, I can only construct PageC without issues.
What I've considered

I could modify all three page structs to use Arc<ApiClient>, but I don't want the need of one struct to influence the design of the other ones.
I could implement the ApiClient trait for &HttpApiClient, Rc<HttpApiClient>, and Arc<HttpApiClient>. This seems feasible, but I’m unsure if it's considered best practice or introduces unnecessary complexity.
I know that HttpApiClient can be cheaply cloned in this example, but in my actual application, the dependency is more expensive to clone and must be shared between pages.


"This seems feasible, but I’m unsure if it's considered best practice or introduces unnecessary complexity." That would be fine, assuming that the implementation is safe. See here for a way to reduce code duplication.
